# How to determine which call to throw is caught in a catch block?

Tags: ruby

If there are few places in the code that could `throw` an object, is it possible to figure out which `throw` actually run?

```rb
x = catch(:x) do 
  throw(:x, foo) if foo
  throw(:x, bar) if bar
end
```

Is it `foo` or `bar` (assuming that the value is not enough to figure out)?

If it was a regular exception it would be possible to simply check the exception's backtrace to figure out where is was raised.

The question is inspired by debugging a `warden` gem which is using `throw`/`catch` to pass a message from the lower middleware levels to the main gem's middleware.

Comment: From my understanding, Ruby's catch / throw is not an error handling mechanism, it's control flow. But anyway, regarding your problem at hand - if you are debugging with `pry` or something, you may be able to call `backtrace` to see where it's coming from. If you're open to modifying the code, then you can pass along an identifier which names the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] is it possible to figure out which throw actually run? [...] The question is inspired by debugging a warden gem

For debugging purposes, Ruby provides [`Tracepoint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/TracePoint.html).

In Ruby terms, [`Kernel::throw`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) is an ordinary method written in C. To see which one was called, you could use:

```
TracePoint.trace(:c_call) do |tp|
  printf("%s:%d\n", tp.path, tp.lineno) if tp.method_id == :throw
end
```

The above code will print the file path and line number each time a C method with the name `throw` is called.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of a `catch` block when `throw` is called is the second argument to `throw`. If no second argument is provided to `throw` then the return value is `nil`.

From the docs for [`Kernel#catch`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/catch):

> If throw(tag2, val) is called, Ruby searches up its stack for a `catch` block whose `tag` has the same `object_id` as *tag2*. When found, the block stops executing and returns *val* (or `nil` if no second argument was given to `throw`).

Here are some examples:

```
# Returns the second argument to throw
catch(:x) { throw(:x, 'foo') }
=> "foo"

# Raises exception
catch(:x) { throw(:y, 'foo') }
UncaughtThrowError: uncaught throw :y

# Returns first throw's second argument
catch(:x) do
  throw(:x, 'foo')
  throw(:x, 'bar')
end
=> "foo"

# Returns second throw's second argument
catch(:x) do
  throw(:x, 'foo') if false
  throw(:x, 'bar')
end
=> "bar"

# Skips both throws and returns the last expression in the block
catch(:x) do
  throw(:x, 'foo') if false
  throw(:x, 'bar') if false
  'baz'
end
=> "baz"
```

The return values are strings in these examples but they can be of any type.